# Why would you try-catch around a promise? Does that catch the promise's error?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I stumbled upon some code that looked off to me:

```
try {
  somePromise()
    .then(res => console.log(res));
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

If some `somePromise()` fails, would this not get caught, and the app would crash? Does this try-catch even do anything?

Should be this, correct?:

```
  somePromise()
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: That does indeed seem wrong.

Comment: `somePromise()` could still throw an error.

Comment: @FelixKling so the try-catch around it would still crash you're saying because the promise error isn't really handled?

Comment: I'm just saying that inside `somePromise` an error could be thrown before the promise is returned.

Comment: `somePromise` is within the `try` block, therefore any unhandled exception thrown by that function (in this invokation) definitely will be catched.

Comment: Exceptions bubble up the scope until they are catched. If not catched at all, the script terminates.

Comment: `try {(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {if (undefinedVar === true) {resolve('success');}})).then(res => console.log(res));} catch (err) {console.log("the error:", err);}` why does this still halt the script instead of catching the ReferenceError thrown by `undefinedVar`?

Comment: Undeclared variable errors are not exceptions. A catch block can handle exceptions occurring while the function is running (`somePromise` in this case). Asynchronous callbacks are not catched in this block, since they don't run in this time. Therefore the `catch` method is provided.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone "asynchronous callbacks are not catched...Therefore the catch method is provided." That makes sense, since this works and logs the error: `(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {if (undefinedVar === true) {resolve('success');}})).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err=>console.log('caugh it!', err));` "Undeclared variable exceptions are not exceptions" that seems wrong, since this also works and logs the error as I would expect: `try{if(undefinedVar===true){alert('??')}}catch(err){console.log('error was:',err)}`

Comment: So thanks for clearing up the async part!

Comment: You are right. "undeclared not an exception" is wrong. I mixed up thoughts about es6 and v8/node. Common JS actually catches it as runtime error.

Comment: It's better to use try/catch to catch runtime errors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TL;DR - If a function that returns a promise throws an exception before returning the promise then that exception would have to be caught in a regular try-catch block.

Consider this function

```
function asyncAdd(x,y){
   if(x === 2){
        throw new Error("good old exception")
   }else if(x === 1) { 
      return Promise.reject("fancy exception")
   }

   return Promise.resolve(x+y)
}
```

This would print "Try caught good old exception"

```
try{
  asyncAdd(2,10).then(x =>console.log("result", x)).catch(y => console.error("Promise caught", y));
}catch (e){
  console.error("Try caught", e);
}
```

This would print "Promise caught fancy exception"

```
try{
  asyncAdd(1,10).then(x =>console.log("result", x)).catch(y => console.error("Promise caught", y));
}catch (e){
  console.error("Try caught", e);
}
```

Comment: I might add that one should not create their own code that can both throw and return a promise.  Though you might have to protect against other's code that does that, you should not allow your own code to do that because it creates code that is a pain to safely use.

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with a rubbish function that could return a Promise *or* throw an Error, that is truly unfortunate. I would recommend a generic `tryCatch` utility like below to deal with the offensive function.

```js
const badFunction = x =>
{ if (x)
    return Promise.resolve(x)
  else
    throw Error('this is a bad function')
}

const tryCatch = (f, ...args) =>
  new Promise(r => r(f(...args)))

tryCatch(badFunction, 1)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
// 1

tryCatch(badFunction, 0)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
// Error: this is a bad function
```

---

**Fix it if you can**

If the rubbish function is under your control to fix, then I would recommending writing it something like this

```js
const goodFunction = x =>
{ if (x)
    return Promise.resolve(x)
  else
    return Promise.reject(Error('this is a good function'))
}

goodFunction(1).then(console.log, console.error)
// 1

goodFunction(0).then(console.log, console.error)
// Error: this is a good function
```

---

**Uncaught errors in `.then`-chained functions**

That's not to say that sometimes we still might encounter a situation where you will need to use a function that could throw. For example, if we `then` a function that can throw – `JSON.parse` in this case - Promises are already equipped to handle this in a convenient way; the thrown Error will be captured inside of a rejected promise

```js
const goodFunction = x =>
  Promise.resolve(x)
  
goodFunction('"abc"')
  .then(JSON.parse)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
  // 'abc'

goodFunction('abc')
  .then(JSON.parse)
  .then(console.log, console.error)
  // 'Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0'
```

---

**Uncaught errors in Promise executor**

If a function throws an error in your Promise executor, don't worry, the error will be contained in an automatically rejected promise -

```js
const okFunction = x =>
  new Promise(resolve => resolve(JSON.parse(x)))

okFunction('"abc"').then(console.log, console.error)
// 'abc'

okFunction('abc').then(console.log, console.error)
// Error: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
```